# Tomcat Thread pool per webapp

Tags: tomcat, web-applications, configuration, tomcat8

Does tomcat supports thread pool configuration for each webapp.
I think all webapps share the pool configured for the connector in tomcat.

Let's say I have webapps A and B, and A is more critical webapp. Let's
say my connector's pool size is 100, and there are 100 concurrent
requests destined for A and B each (so total 200 requests here). I
would like to allocate 70 threads to process A's requests, and only 30
for B's.

Note : We dont want to use multiple tomcat instances running,or run applications on different ports
We need same container config except the thread configuration per webapp..

Is there any example config /link for the same.

Answer (score 1):

Tomcat does not support it.
Thread pool setting is specified at executor or connector level in server.xml and cannot be specified at application level (in context.xml).

See also:
https://serverfault.com/questions/351830/tomcat-configure-maxthreads-per-webapp